# Просмотр страницы

Tags: python

[исходная страница](http://dom.59.ru/realty/sell/residential/new/1.php)

имеется страница. на ней отражается определенное кол-во объявлений.

как заставить python отразить больше объявления на одной странице,
чтоб потом загрузить всю страницу в переменную?
использую модуль для работы с html

**import requests**
**from bs4 import BeautifulSoup**

[image: кол-во объявление]

Comment: а в чем проблема? `url='http://dom.59.ru/realty/sell/residential/new/1.php?order=DateUpdate&dir=desc&PriceUnit=1&AreaUnit=1&expand=0&PriceUnit=1#1.php%order=DateUpdate&dir=desc&PriceUnit=1&AreaUnit=1&expand=0&PriceUnit=1'` ну и далее как обычно...

Comment: проблема в том что python загружает только первые 50 объявлений. а мне надо чтоб страница отображала больше , например 300 объявлений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За количество отображаемых объявлений отвечает значение cookie list_col_pp. Можно попробовать запросить данные следующим образом:

```
import requests
cookies = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
cookies.set("list_col_pp", "200")
response = equests.get("http://dom.59.ru/realty/sell/residential/new/1.php?order=Da&dir=desc&PriceUnit=1&AreaUnit=1&expand=0&PriceUnit=1", cookies=cookies)
```

Или можно запросить используя POST запрос как это делается при изменении количества отображаемых объявлений:

```
response = requests.post("http://dom.59.ru/realty/sell/residential/new/1.php?order=Da&dir=desc&PriceUnit=1&AreaUnit=1&expand=0&PriceUnit=1", data={"action": "get_block", "name": "main"}, cookies=cookies)
```